# alpha opacity and behavior: url(iepngfix.htc); not working in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, behavior, iepngfix

```
.idioma_es #logosFooter, .idioma_es #logosFooter li a {
    background: url(../nImg/microsites/logos/logos_footer.png) no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    behavior: url(../../nJs/iepngfix.htc);

}
```

Result in Firefox:
[image: result in firefox]

Result in Internet Explorer 6 (Based on IE Tester for Windows):
[image: result in Ie]

the path of the .htc file is correct !

Any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't test this with IETester. It's not completely reliable.

You should use a [virtual machine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575), but you can quickly test a page with http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/.

---

After Googling a little, I might have been a little unfair to IETester (though I still don't trust it).

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

> Known problems and limitations :
>
> - CSS Filters are not working correctly in user mode : A solution is to launch IETester as admin user and CSS Filters will work.

Comment: i did.. actually if I paste the path in the adress bar i can download the file :(

Comment: I can't USE a VM or an online tester because it's local; can't upload it untill its ready :(
Do you think that it's posible that IEtester is messing with me??

Comment: Yes. Put it live in a new, temporary folder with `behavior: url(http://absolute-path/iepngfix.htc);`, and provide a link and I'll tell you if it's working.

Comment: That was it; tested in a mate's computer with IE6. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can try PIE - http://css3pie.com, that is working in IE6 too.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 does not support the alpha channel for background images apart from in specific circumstances. There is no general fix, as there is for foreground images.

Look here: http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Check the first bit of text under 'The pitfalls' heading