# Desaturate image in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: css, filter, internet-explorer-6

I'm using the following code in my css to desaturate images in IE browsers:

```
-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)';
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1);
```

It works ok in IE7-9, but I can't make it work in IE6. Any ideas on which filter expression to use for IE6?

Comment: Are you using IE6 in a virtual machine, or are you using some other wacky way?

Comment: @thirtydot - i was testing in IEtester - you suspiciuos that it won't work in it? Will test on virtual now...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079505/alpha-opacity-and-behavior-urliepngfix-htc-not-working-in-ie6/7079827#7079827

Comment: @thirtydot - Running IEtester as admin didn't help - but it works ok on virtual machine in IE6. Guess problem solved - post as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to this: [alpha opacity and behavior: url(iepngfix.htc); not working in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079505/alpha-opacity-and-behavior-urliepngfix-htc-not-working-in-ie6/7079827#7079827)

> Don't test this with IETester. It's not completely reliable.
>
> You should use a [virtual
>   machine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575),
>   but you can quickly test a page with http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/.

Although, I am surprised that running IETester with administrative privileges didn't fix it.

Comment: The virtual machine displays it ok.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be grayscale.js:

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/

Comment: The library uses the same syntax as I posted in my question to solve IE6 grayscale image. The problem will still occur - problem is that I was testing in IEtester, which does not render filters correctly.